# Ubuntu 20.04: Wifi DNS suddenly not working

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, dns, ubuntu-20.04

Since a few days, my room's Wifi doesn't work on my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04). Other Wifi networks show no problems. If I use `ping` and `traceroute` with a domain name, they fail with the error *"temporary failure in name resolution"*. If I use them with an IP address, they succeed. Hence, it's probably a DNS issue. My phone shows no problems with the room's Wifi, only the laptop. Recently, I didn't do any system update or network setting changes.

What I have tried without success:

1. I already tried different Wifi networks (phone, office), and they all work.
2. A wired connection to the same router shows the same problem.
3. I tried inserting a fixed DNS in Wifi settings (Settings > Wifi > ⚙ > IPv4 > DNS, set to 8.8.8.8 and deactivate "automatic"), still no name resolution.
4. I disconnected and re-connected several times, the problem persists.
5. I deleted the Wifi and re-connected to no avail.
6. Run `dhclient` in the console.

The problem only occurs in the combination laptop + room Wifi. I can work around this problem by using a VPN to which I connect via its IP address. It's a workaround at best.

I would like to restart the router to see whether that helps, but unfortunately, it's not under my control. So, I first want to try to determine whether the problem is on my side or on the router side.

What else could I try? Is it even my laptop's problem or probably the router? The fact that other devices are normal lets me believe that it's maybe my laptop's problem.

Comment: I got the same error but coudn't resolve this issue? I believe you have alredy got this issue. Can you pls update here?

Comment: If I recall correctly, it worked again after I reset my system to an earlier state with [Timeshift](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift). But it is only applicable if you already have a system snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue for a couple of days after lots of research I was able to fix this issue by running the below commands.

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
sudo nmcli networking off
sudo nmcli networking on
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
nmcli connection show --activeenter
```